# Background app and NSTextField in NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa

I hide the dock icon of my Cocoa app with

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess };
TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToBackgroundApplication);
```

My code loads a NIB file and displays the window of that NIB (`makeKeyAndOrderFront:`) when the user clicks on a statusbar menu item. The window contains a NSTextField.

I am not able to enter text into this text field. It seems that the window is not activated correctly.

When not hiding the dock icon with the code mentioned above, text input works fine.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem.

Basically it's making the app an agent app by default and bring back the dock icon programmatically if necessary.

See [my blog](http://codebrickie.com/blog/2012/10/16/switching-between-dock-and-status-bar-mode-in-cocoa/) for details.

Comment: Could you please share more details about the fix, since your blog is down?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication]  activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[[textField window] makeFirstResponder: textField];
```